# Tracing memory address for an image loaded into memory on linux

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, trace, memory-address

I am trying to trace information everytime an image on linux is loaded into memory. Ideally, I would need

- the pid of the process,
- the timestamp of the event,
- path from where the image is being loaded,
- and also the location in memory where the image gets loaded.

I have managed to get the pid, timestamp and path using the `open_exec` tracepoint available on linux, but I'm having problems tracing the memory location where the image is loaded. Any suggestions (tracepoints,markers, syscalls, etc) how I could trace this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea could be to trace all mmap(2) calls, in a manner similar to how strace(1) traces calls (srace uses ptrace(2) APIs). You can try yourself by checking out what strace seen by using `strace (some command) 2> FOO` and then grep `mmap  FOO`:

```
mmap2(NULL, 40654, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb80e5000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb80e4000
mmap2(0x724000, 37456, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x724000
mmap2(0x72c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7) = 0x72c000
mmap2(0x27e000, 117704, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x27e000
mmap2(0x299000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a) = 0x299000
mmap2(0x697000, 17008, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x697000
mmap2(0x69b000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3) = 0x69b000
```

You have the corresponding file name of each descriptor (from open(2)), and the return value of mmap(2) will be the address where the image is mapped in memory.

Depending on how you can intercept the process, you can also inject a hook on dlopen, though the above should be enough

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try to use SystemTap to intercept mmap2() calls :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the kernel I am working with does not support hooking specific system calls (it does not have the CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO or CONFIG_KPROBES enabled for SystemTap). Therefore, I cannot use SystemTap. I was looking for workarounds in order to avoid rebuilding the kernel and I found that perf can be used to relate userspace images path with their location in memory, using mmap(). Would you have any pointers on how to use perf to achieve this ?